# multiple signingkeys for one git profile

Tags: git, yubikey, git-sign

I wanna sign my git commits with yubikeys. For backup reasons I have two with a different key on each one. Now I want to sign my commits with the keys on the yubikey. Adding multiple keys to the web gui does not seem to be a problem, but I have issues adding multiple signingkeys to my git config.

Is it possible to assign one profile two or more possible signingkeys? Therefore if yubikey A is attached, it will sign with this key, but with the other if yubikey B is attached?